# How to add [] as elements to a list of lists in Python?

Tags: python, list

```
a = [["GE", "US", "UK", ....], [12, 11, 29, ...]]
```

now I want to add other 5 variables and make the results like:

```
a = [["GE", "US", "UK", ....], [12, 11, 29, ...], ["a", "b", "c", ...], [...], [...], ...]
```

Comment: SO is not a homework resolver place ! you need to add your code !

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can append every list that you want to add by:

```
a.append(["a", "b", "c"])
```

Answer (score 1):

You can just use the `+` operator to concatenate lists

```
>>> a = [["GE", "US", "UK"], [12, 11, 29]]
>>> a += [['a','b','c'], [],[],[]]
>>> a
[['GE', 'US', 'UK'], [12, 11, 29], ['a', 'b', 'c'], [], [], []]
```